# Arithmetic progression question

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

In an arithmetic progression there are $2n$ arguments. The sum of last $n$ arguments is three times greater than that of the first n arguments. It is also known that the last argument in the series is $6$ times smaller than the sum of the two center arguments.  calculate $d$.

attempt at a solution:

from the data we have:
$$\frac{n}2 (2 a_1 + (n-1)d)3 =  \frac{n}2 (2 (a_1 +dn) + (n-1)d)
$$
which eventually simplifies to : $2 a_1 = d$

We will call this formula $1$

We then also have: 
$ a_n+a_{n+1} = a_{2n} * 6$

which can also be presented as: $a_1 + (n-1)d + a_1 +dn = (a_1 + (2n-1)d)*6   $

further simplification: $2a_1 +2dn -d =6a_1 +12dn - 6d $

substituting formula $1$ into this formula yields (after several operations): $0 = 10n-3$

or $n = \frac 3 {10}$   .

not quite what one would expect....

Comment: Please explain or define *d*.

Comment: $d$ - the common difference of an arithmetic progression.

Comment: you are summing the $n $last arguments of the series, not $2n$

Comment: Or else what makes you think this way?

Comment: Yes but  ,by it's own ,it has no influence in the first formula, nor is it related to it.

Comment: You are I think right. Need more coffee.

Comment: on the RHS of equation 1, I think you need to fix +(n−1)d) and change it to +(2n−1)d)

Comment: I don't think so, since I'm summing $n$ arguments on that side, and not the entire progression. The $n$ last arguments of the progression that is.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$
2a_1=d; \tag{1}
$$

$$
2a_1 + (2n-1)d = 6a_1 + 6(2n-1)d; \tag{2}
$$

Substituting formula $(1)$ into $(2)$, we have:

$$
(10n-3)d=0. \tag{3}
$$

Since $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then

$$
d=0.
$$

I think, it is trivial arithmetic progression:

$$
a_1=a_2=...=a_{2n}=0.
$$

(Hmm, $0$ is $6$ times smaller than $0$... In general, it is true: $0 = 6\cdot 0$).

---

If we'll **modify** the problem:

...  the last argument in the series is **smaller by $6$** than the sum of the two center arguments ..., then

$$
(a_1+...+a_n) \cdot 3 = (a_{n+1}+...+a_{2n}),  
$$
$$
a_n+a_{n+1}  = a_{2n}+6,  
$$

then we'll have
$$
2a_1=d, \tag{1'}
$$
$$
2a_1+(2n-1)d=a_1+(2n-1)d+6. \tag{2'}
$$

Corollary, $a_1=6$, $d=12$.

Examples:

$2n=2$: $~~~6, 18$;

$2n=4$: $~~~6, 18, 30, 42$;

$2n=6$: $~~~6, 18, 30, 42, 54, 66$;

$...$

(solution and examples for **modified** problem).

Comment: $d$ cannot be zero since it says that the last $ n$ arguments are greater than the first $n$ arguments, which must indicate some sort of increment and $d$ therefore cannot be $0$.

Comment: In general, $a$ is $3$ times greater than $b$, iif $a = 3b$. But when $a=b=0$, we can say "3 times greater" too: $~~~0 = 3\cdot 0.~~~$ Isn't it?

Comment: Generally speaking yes, In this case however...also all arguments cant be zero since it contradicts the known data.

Comment: I can't find other reasonable answer...

Comment: Since (from first condition) the difference (d) is twice the first term (a1) it follows that the arguments are the odd integers (1,3,5,7,...) each multiplied by the value a1. For non-zero a1, the ratio of the 2n'th argument to the sum of the middle two arguments is 3/4, 7/8, 11/12, 15/16,... respectively for n=1,2,3,4,... so clearly the 2n'th argument is never going to be one-sixth of the middle two. This only leaves the trivial solution (a1 is zero) but that fits any arbitrary values for the two conditions (not just 3 and 6 as stated), which seems a bit unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Bak1139, if we will change " is 6 times smaller" into "is smaller by 6", then the problem will get reasonable form (I updated the answer for this case:).

Comment: Yes indeed...it looks like some kind of typo given the fact that their answers match what you wrote here